# Gathering System Process IO details

Tags: powershell, system, taskmanager

I am trying to prepare a report wherein I need to collect the I/O read,write and other bytes of all the process running on the system. Below is the script which I currently use.

```
Get-Process|select name,cpu,@{name="WorkingSet";Expression={$_.WorkingSet/1kb}},BasePriority,path|where {$_.Name -in 'dllhost','firefox','dsapi'}
```

Below is output that we obtain after a few processing and measure object.

[image]

The issue which I am facing is that for most of the system processes or where the username is **system**,  the value for those returns mostly in the form **zero**. Kindly provide some directions on how to fix this issue and obtain the actual value for the system process as well.

<>
From what I read on the I/O values will not be extracted from the get-process cmdlet which is why I have used the below cmdlet and it works fine for user created process however for the system created process the script returns a zero value as show in the above image.

```
$gc = get-counter '\Process(dllhost)\IO Read Bytes/sec'
$gc.countersamples | sort cookedvalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're running powershell as administrator.

There is no ReadByteSec or WriteBytpeSec from what I can see.
You're also using a select statement which doesn't contain those properties.

Type this to see all the available properties for dllhost:

```
$processes = Get-Process | where {$_.Name -in 'dllhost'}
Get-Member -InputObject $processes[0]
```

And then add those to your statement:

Get-Process|select name,cpu,@{name="WorkingSet";Expression={$*.WorkingSet/1kb}},BasePriority,path, ***BytesField1, BytesField2, etc*** |where {$*.Name -in 'dllhost','firefox','dsapi'}

Comment: @OptilMysticall  I have updated the questions. Had missed adding the snippet from where I get the I/O details. Please check it now